# Changes in 'Templates' does not change anything in Apache Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, format, ide, auto-generate

Good day. I am trying to change the auto-generated main class in Netbeans.

By default, whenever I make a new project, Netbeans automatically creates the class below:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

/**
 *
 * @author Salti
 */
public class Mavenproject1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

However, I'd like it to be like this:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;


public class Mavenproject1 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
    }
}
```

I tried changing the ***'Java Main Class'*** located in ***'Tools->Templates->Java"***. However, any changes I make there amount to nothing as there is still no change in the auto-generated class when I create a new project. I also made sure to save the changes, as well as restart Netbeans, but still to no avail.

Thank you very much!

More info in case it is needed:

Win11
Apache Netbeans IDE 18

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you have encountered a usability bug/issue with NetBeans: for a Maven project it is not currently possible to specify the the template to be used when creating a Maven class containing the `main()` method. See [NetBeans issue #3678 Creating new application (Java With Maven, Java Application) has main class built ignoring templates](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/3678), which is open and unresolved. But the change you describe in your question works fine when creating Ant applications (**File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Application**)